# MySQL returned datatype and python outputs different type for different functions

Tags: python, mysql, qt, pyqt, mysql-python

I am having plenty of problems with the MySQL returns and entering it into a Qt table with python.  I use `data = cursor.fetchall()`

```
for data in data:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        sqlTableWidget.setItem(index,i,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data[i]))
    index = index +1
```

Originally I would put str() around the return, and that worked for everything except when i had unicode problems with foreign language and on the datetime.  So now I dont put str() and the foreign language inserts to the table.  However, there are some problems now with non strings

1) I cant insert datetime.  When i do `type(data[i])`, it returns `datetime` and when I try to convert it to a string using `data[i] = data[i].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` it tells me `'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

2) So i just passed that for now.  Now I try to get integers to display.  I do

```
if data[i] == 1:
    print data[i]
    print type(data[i])
    data[i] = str(data[i])
```

this results in:

```
>>1
>>(type 'long')
>>Type Error: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

additionally, if I try to do

```
print list(data[i])
```

it returns:

```
TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable
```

furthermore,

```
if data[i] is None:
    data[i] = 'No data'
sqlTableWidget.setItem(index,i,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data[i]))
```

returns:

```
QTableWidgetItem(QtableWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

I must be missing something fundamentally about my returns.  What causes this?

Comment: `data` is somehow a `tuple`.  You're trying to change the value of a tuple element, but you can't because `tuple` are immutable.

Comment: then why does it tell me the type is long both when i query the data item and when I try to convert it to a list?

Comment: `data[i]` is a `long`, `data` (the container holding the `long`) is a `tuple`.

Comment: but im not asking type(data), im asking type(data[i]) , which should return the type of data[i], not data correct?

Comment: Sure, but that parts not the problem.  The problem is _on the next line_ where you try to assign a string to `data[i]`.  Since `data` is immutable, it doesn't support item assignment and raises the error.  (Changing an element contained in `data` is a change in `data`)

Comment: okay i understand that now, what about the NoneType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the data from the fetchall method since it is a tuple and not a list.
The easiest fix would be to do:

```
data = [list(i) for i in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: okay that changed the return type on data, but elements inside still seem to be tuple, is there a way to make all returned elements into list, like a recursive setup?

Answer (score 1):

From your error log, I think problem happens because tuple in python doesn't support assignment.

Return values you fetch are ready-only tuple so it's invalid to change value directly on that.

In your code :

```
    data[i] = data[i].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Do you want to revise original data stored in DB directly? If not, you could use another variable with list type, like:

```
    my_list = data[i].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    // TODO MORE
```

Otherwise you may rely on update sentence to reivse data in DB.

Comment: thanks, this works for temporarily storing it, but it doesnt work for my issue of the types being different, for example, the NoneType still does not enter the if statement but then errors on the next line.  do you know what this is ?

Comment: @user1938107 I am a little confused, I guess your problem is about writing into read-only tuple before, so does that mean your question change now? sorry for my native language isn't English.